# Java GraphQL schema dependency across modules

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, graphql, spring-graphql

I have a gradle project that is divided into multiple modules. There is a shared module that defines a root GraphQL schema that I want to expose to other modules but I'm not sure how to define this dependency in other modules. Also a requirement is that IntelliJ IDEA would be able to resolve the types in the other modules' GraphQL schema to their definitions in the shared module's schema.

For example, my project has the following structure:

```
projectRoot
  |-- shared/src/main/resources/graphql
  |   `-- schema.graphql
  |-- user/src/main/resources/graphql
  |   `-- schema.graphql
  `-- task/src/main/resources/graphql
      `-- schema.graphql
```

In `shared/src/main/resources/graphql/schema.graphql` I have defined the following:

```
type Mutation {}
type Query {}
```

And in `user/src/main/resources/graphql/schema.graphql` I have defined the following:

```
extend type Mutation {}
extend type Query {}
```

I have defined a dependency on the shared module in the user module's gradle.build file as follows:

```
dependencies {
    api(project(":shared")) // I have tried implementation also
}
```

I am unable to run the project as I have a few other things to sort out also but IDEA is unable to resolve the types:
[image]

The GraphQL I'm using is [Spring for GraphQL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current/reference/html/)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there are two different problems that need to be solved: the Spring for GraphQL auto-detection of schema files, and the IntelliJ IDEA plugin support.

First, if you've structured your application this way, you should tell Spring Boot to [look for schema files in the entire classpath](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.graphql.schema) with a configuration property:

```
spring.graphql.schema.locations="classpath*:graphql/**/"
```

Second, the IntelliJ IDEA plugin for GraphQL support is relying on [the `.graphqlconfig` specification](https://github.com/kamilkisiela/graphql-config/blob/legacy/specification.md#use-cases). In your case, you could add a `.graphqlconfig` file at the root of your project with the following:

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "shared": {
      "includes": ["./shared/src/main/resources/graphql/*.graphql"]
    },
    "user": {
      "includes": ["./user/src/main/resources/graphql/*.graphql"]
    },
    "task": {
      "includes": ["./task/src/main/resources/graphql/*.graphql"]
    }
  }
}
```

You can [check out the plugin documentation](https://jimkyndemeyer.github.io/js-graphql-intellij-plugin/docs/developer-guide#setting-up-multi-schema-projects-using-graphql-config) since there are multiple ways to structure your configuration for this use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this did not work for me. I went back to monolithic - I might try this again sometime in the future when I get the time.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what’s not working? What are you seeing?